# Is there an easy way to attach an email in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is there an easy way to add an email (from Outlook) into a card on Trello?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is no - because you used the word Outlook.

Superuser.se has a question [How to save a mail into an .eml-file with Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/75581/how-to-save-a-mail-into-an-eml-file-with-outlook) and although it looks like it might be possible I wouldn't classify any of the solutions as *easy*.

Thunderbird on the other hand lets you save an email as an *.eml* or *.html* file via the right mouse popup.

Then you'd simply add the .eml or .html as an attachment to your card in Trello. Then if it needs to be viewed, click on the attachment link on the card. If you used an eml file then your browser will probably download it as normal rather than launch it directly as it would for the html file, but once downloaded, double click the .eml file and your email client will pick it up and display it. Again - for me this is Thunderbird and it works beautifully.

Outlook, however - mmmnot so easy.

Two workarounds come to mind though:

- Print the email to a PDF file using something like [BullZip PDF](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) and attach the PDF to the Trello card.
- Snag a screenshot and attach the image of the email to the Trello card.

Comment: The pdf idea is an excellent one.

Answer (score 2):

You can add email from Outlook or any other mail client (desktop or mobile) via [Emello](http://emelloapp.com). You can assign custom dedicated email addresses to any of your boards and lists. This should fix your work flow issue.

Comment: The link looks broken. Emello seems dead

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the email, save it as an htm file and then attach it to a card in Trello.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Download [www.outlook2web.com](http://www.outlook2web.com) and then you can drag an email from Outlook directly to Trello. It is saved as a .msg file.